# Insert rows into a protected data table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a protected sheet that I've created that has tables which has some columns that I would like protected. However, I need the end user to retain the ability to insert rows into the table. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you protect the sheet if you check the option "Insert rows" does that not allow them to do what you want?

Comment: nope I have all of the options enabled and still no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

[Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx)

> When you protect a worksheet, all cells are locked by default, which
>   means that they cannot be edited. To enable cells to be edited while
>   leaving only some cells locked, you can unlock the cells and then lock
>   only specific cells and ranges before you protect the worksheet. You
>   can also enable specific users to edit specific ranges in a protected
>   worksheet.